# Clicking on element in terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I've noticed that hyperlinks printed in my Debian/Linux terminal are clickable and open the browser when clicked.

I was wondering if this could be used for other things or if this was just hard-coded in the terminal for hyperlinks only.

Is it possible to print out a line in Python that when clicked will launch another process, for example?

Answer (score 1):

URL support is hard coded in the individual terminal emulator.

The terminal may support arbitrary URIs as registered in whichever environment it calls home, so that you can e.g. write a Gnome extension for myapp://something and have it work in gnome-terminal, but this is entirely terminal specific.

It's also possible for a terminal program in any terminal to receive mouse events and it can then do whatever it wants with them (like how `elinks` lets you click non-URL links to browse). However, this requires the program to be running in the foreground and controlling everything that appears on that terminal.